# Clarification regarding the limit of (x)sin(1/x)

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I know the limit of $\lim \limits_{x\to 0} x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 0$ and I understand the proof, but I'm confused as to why $\lim \limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$ doesn't apply here. Does it only hold for certain values of $x$?

I know I'm making a mistake somewhere but I'm not sure where. I've read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674466/why-isnt-the-limit-of-sin1-x-1-x-as-x-goes-to-zero-1), but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Edit: The reason I was relating the two limits is because they seem to share a similar format.

$$\lim \limits_{x\to 0} x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim \limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{(\frac{1}x)}$$

Then if we let $y=\frac{1}{x}$ we get $\lim \limits_{y\to 0} \frac{\sin(y)}{y}$ except that when $x$ tends to $0$, $y$ tends to $\infty$. This lead me to believe that the right way to set this up would be $\lim \limits_{y\to \infty} \frac{\sin(y)}{y} = 0$.

My mistake was in understanding the substitution step. I was unaware that for the substitution to be valid both sides must approach $0$ as $x$ approaches $0$, and if not then the limits should be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: This limit is equivalent to $$\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}x$$which is not the same thing as $$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$$

Answer (score 1):

The first limit corresponds to

$$\lim \limits_{x\to 0} x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 0 \iff\lim \limits_{y\to \infty} \frac{\sin y}{y} = 0$$

which is completely different from the standard limit

$$\lim \limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$

Indeed, as you noticed, by $y=\frac1{|x|}\to \infty$ and since $\forall \theta$ we have $|\sin \theta|\le 1$, by squeeze theorem

$$\left| \frac{\sin y}{y}\right|\le \left| \frac{1}{y}\right|=\frac1y \to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$ 0 \leq |x \sin (\frac 1 x)| \leq |x|$ for all $x \neq 0$. By squeeze Theorem we see that the limit is $0$.

This is not related to $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {sin x} x$